# confusion with NSindexpathforselectedrow

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, logic, nsindexpath

Long story short, I'm revisiting an old project and would just enjoy an explanation regarding indexPathForSelectedRow!

Basically, I had the initial table view displaying the values 1,2, or 3, similar to this array.

```
var array1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

once a user selected 1,2, or 3, they would be segued to a second table view displaying the values of the corresponding nested array.

```
var array 2 = [["11", "12"], ["25", "27"], ["36", "39"]]
```

For example, if a user selected 2 in the first table view, they would be brought to the second table containing the values of 25 and 27.

This was accomplished using this code

```
if let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? RestaurantNameTable {
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
destViewController.selectedRestaurants = array2[indexPath.section]
```

Here is my confusion.

I understand that the indexPathForSelectedRow refers to a section and row.

However, upon selection of the first array, there is no section, just 3 rows.  So why is it that using the nsindexpathforselectedrow of array 1 (which is 3 rows) still refers to the correct section/array in array2?  Esepecially if im referring to the sections of array2?

In otherwords, if I choose any row in array1, I have no section.... how is it that I am able to say that the array2 section is = to the indexpath when all indexpath is is just a row #?

Unless my understanding is flawed, choosing "2" in array1 has a section of 0 and row of 1, but the contents of array2, "25" & "27" have a section of 1?  How does this logic work?

If you would like a new phrasing of this question, please ask.  I'm having a hard time myself, haha.

Regardless, thanks for looking and for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The section number doesn't reflect the number of sections, it's just an id assigned to it. So for array1, the section is 0 because the first section is always assigned 0, unless you set it otherwise. Similar to arrays, and how the first index of an array is 0, the first section is 0.

So the problem I believe you're facing with array1, is that it's a single dimensional array. Meaning, for a one dimensional array such as array1, when you use "indexPathForSelectedRow", it's looking for the the 0th array(section 0), within the main array and then it's trying to retrieve the row from that inner array. Thus, it isn't finding the array at at all because there is none(since it's a single dimension). So if you did this(which puts that original array, within another array):

```
let array1 = [["1", "2", "3"]]
```

and then did this:

```
if let destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? RestaurantNameTable {
let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
destViewController.selectedRestaurants = array2[indexPath.section]
```

then it would work exactly the same as array2. because it's grabbing the 0th array(section 0) and then grabbing the correct row tied to the index path selected.